# Quick strlen question

Tags: c, string, strlen

I've come to bother you all with another probably really simple C question.

Using the following code:

```
int get_len(char *string){

    printf("len: %lu\n", strlen(string));

    return 0;
}

int main(){

    char *x = "test";
    char y[4] = {'t','e','s','t'};

    get_len(x); // len: 4
    get_len(y); // len: 6

    return 0;
}
```

2 questions. Why are they different and why is y 6? Thanks guys.

EDIT: Sorry, I know what would fix it, I kind of just wanted to understand what was going on. So does strlen just keep forwarding the point till it happens to find a \0? Also when I did strlen in the main function instead of in the get_len function both were 4. Was that just a coincidence?

Comment: Yes, it was just a coincidence.

Comment: As an aside to the answers (which are excellent if a bit repetitive) I would point out that while `"test"` is a convenient syntax for the sequence `'t','e','s','t',0`, you can in fact as a special case initialize a char array with `char y[4]="test";` in which case the final 0 will be omitted (there is simply no room for it in `y`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`y` is not null-terminated.  `strlen()` counts characters until it hits a null character.  Yours happened to find one after 6, but it could be any number.  Try this:

`char y[] = {'t','e','s','t', '\0'};`

Here's what an implementation of `strlen()` might look like (off the top of my head -- don't have my K&R book handy, but I believe there's an implementation given there):

```
size_t strlen(const char* s)
{
    size_t result = 0;
    while (*s++) ++result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So is strlen just forwarding the pointer until it finds some \0 anywhere it can?

Comment: @LearningC: Exactly.  It keeps incrementing the pointer and looking at what's there.  When it finds a zero, it stops and returns how many characters it looked at (excluding the zero).

Comment: @LearningC: Yes. Or until it crashes with a segfault instead. Or until it formats your hard drive. The behavior is *undefined* if your input is not zero-terminated. *Anything* can happen.

Comment: AndreyT is correct.  In practice, it'll often find a null before anything bad happens.  But you can never be sure.  I doubt it would ever actually format your hard drive, but you could sure go off into forbidden memory and have a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Fred: Actually, something bad happens the very moment it steps over the byte where the null should have been. Since (assuming 8bit integers) the chance of a null byte being there accidentally is not all that much better than 1/256, in practice something bad happens quite often.

Comment: @Fred before the days of protected memory, this could actually damage your hardware. Some things were mapped into memory and if a value was read from certain addresses then it altered the state of the device, possibly putting it into an invalid state..

Comment: @sbi: If you mean getting the wrong result is "something bad", you're right.  Good point.  My meaning was something even worse than that (crash, etc.)  @Earlz: Sure, but I think that's rather uncommon these days.

Comment: Question: If you were to right a better string copy how could you be sure the string passed to be copied had a \0. Since you couldn't find the length of that "string" you couldn't ask if string[lastchar] == '\0'.

Comment: @LearningC: it would be a requirement on the caller of your function that the string be terminated, just as it is a requirement on the caller of `strlen` or `strcpy` that the input is a nul-terminated string.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
char y[4] = {'t','e','s','t'};
```

*is not a proper zero-terminated string*. It's an array of four characters, ***without*** the terminating `'\0'`. `strlen()` simply counts the characters until it hits a zero. With `y` it simply counts over the end of the array until it accidentally finds a zero byte.
Doing this you are invoking undefined behavior. The code might just as well format your hard drive.

You can avoid this by using the special syntax for character array initialization:

```
char y[] = "test";
```

This initializes `y` with ***five*** characters, since it automatically appends a `'\0'`.
Note that I also left the array's size unspecified. The compiler figures this out itself, and it automatically re-figures if I change the string's length.

BTW, here's a simple `strlen()` implementation:

```
size_t strlen(const char* p)
{
    size_t result = 0;
    while(*p++) ++result;
    return result;
}
```

Modern implementations will likely not fetch individual bytes or even use CPU intrinsics, but this is the basic algorithm.

Comment: Wow, I didn't see your `strlen()` before I added mine.  They're identical!  Great minds...  8v)

Comment: The GNU libc source for the string functions are quite enlightening to poke around in, and surprisingly complex.

Comment: @Fred: Well, it is one of the most fundamental algorithms of the C library and it's a prime example in K&R. No wonder most of us have it imprinted into their memory.

Answer (score 3):

The following is not a null terminated array of characters:

```
 char y[4] = {'t','e','s','t'};
```

Part of `strlen()`'s contract is that it be provided with a pointer to a null terminated string.  Since that doesn't happen with `strlen(y)`, you get undefined behavior.  In your particular case, you get `6` returned, but anything could happen, including a program crash.

From C99's 7.1.1 "Definition of terms":

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
>   character.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` works with *strings*. String is defined as a sequence (array) of characters terminated with `\0` character.

Your `x` points to a string. So, `strlen` works fine with `x` as an argument.

Your `y` is not a string. For this reason, passing `y` to `strlen` results in undefined behavior. The result is meaningless and unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to null-terminate y.

```
int get_len(char *string){

    printf("len: %lu\n", strlen(string));

    return 0;
}

int main(){

    char *x = "test";
    char y[5] = {'t','e','s','t','\0'};

    get_len(x); // len: 4
    get_len(y); // len: 4

    return 0;
}
```

strlen() basically takes the pointer you give it and counts the number of bytes until the next NULL in memory. It just so happened that there was a NULL two bytes later in your memory.

Comment: So is strlen just forwarding the pointer until it finds some \0 anywhere it can?

Comment: Two problems with this.  First, NULL is intended as a null pointer, not a null character.  Second, you've still got `char y[4]`, so you've got an extra initializer.  You need five positions to have a "test" string.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to increment the index, but I did not know about the NULL thing. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

An actual C-type string is one bigger than the number of its characters, since it needs a terminating null character.

Therefore, `char y[4] = {'t','e','s','t'};` doesn't form a string, since it's four characters.  `char y[] = "test";` or `char y[5] = "test";` would form a string, since they'd have a character array of five characters ending with the null-byte terminator.

Answer (score 0):

```
char y[5] = {'t','e','s','t','\0'};
```

would be the same as

```
char *x = "test";
```

Comment: For the purposes of `strlen()`, yes.  However, `y` is an array of five `char`, and its contents can be modified at will.  `x` is a pointer to `char`, and in this case is pointing to a string that cannot reliably be modified.  On the other hand, it's possible to reassign a value to `x` but not to `y`.

Comment: @David Thornley the answer was given in a beginner context just to illustrate what went wrong according to the OP. Now better answers were given. No need to downvote

Comment: IME exactly differences as subtle as this one (`x[0]='x';` is fine when you said `char x[]="X";`, but fatal when you say `char* x="X";`) can never be stressed too much, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you just need to make sure to end a string with the 0 or '\0' character. As a side note, you may check this out: http://bstring.sourceforge.net/ . It has O(1) string length function, unlike the C/C++ strlen which is error prone and slow at O(N), where N is the number of non-null characters. I don't remember the last time when I used strlen and it's friends. Go for safe & fast functions/classes!

Answer (score 0):

when you use the single quotes always use '/0' but in double quotes avoid to use the '/0' in strlen()

Note that the strlen() function doesn't count the null character \0 while calculating the length